# Topological group of invertible linear transformation??

Tags: continuity, linear-transformations, topological-groups

Suppose $L(\mathbb R^n)$ denotes the set of all invertible linear transformation from $\mathbb R^n$ to itself. It is well known that it is a metric space induced by the norm $||A||=\sup_{||x||<1}||Ax||$. We also know that $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ is a continuous mapping. If we define multiplication as composition in $L(\mathbb R^n)$ , is it true that the mapping $F:L(\mathbb R^n)\times L(\mathbb R^n) \to L(\mathbb R^n)$ defined as $F(A,B)=A\circ B$ is continuous? [If it is true then it in turn will prove that $L(\mathbb R^n)$ is a topological group]

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F$ is a bilinear map. And a bilinear map on finite dimensional spaces is always continous.